# Integrate the pull to refresh feature in Ionic 3 with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, ionic-framework, pull-to-refresh

I'm working on a Ionic3 app integrated with Wordpress using REST API v2 and I need to include the **pull to refresh** feature but I don't understand how to do it with my code.

This is my function that retrieves my post

```
getPostsWordpress(){
    if(!(this.posts.length > 0)){
      let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create();
      loading.present();
      this.wordpressService.getRecentPostsWithSort(this.categoryId,this.sort) 
      .subscribe(data => {
        for(let post of data){
          post.excerpt.rendered = post.excerpt.rendered.split('<a')[0] + "</p>";
          this.posts.push(post);
        }
        loading.dismiss();
      });
    }
  }
```

...

```
doInfinite(infiniteScroll) {
    let page = (Math.ceil(this.posts.length/10)) + 1;
    console.log("PAGE_"+page)
    console.log("this.posts.length_"+this.posts.length)
    let loading = true;

    this.wordpressService.getRecentPostsWithSort(this.categoryId,this.sort, page)
    .subscribe(data => {
      for(let post of data){
        if(!loading){
          infiniteScroll.complete();

        }
        post.excerpt.rendered = post.excerpt.rendered.split('<a')[0] + "</p>";
        this.posts.push(post);
        loading = false;
      }
    }, err => {
      this.morePagesAvailable = false; 
    }) 
  }
```

doInfinite let me to implement infinite scroll, and all works well!

How is it possibile to integrate pull to refresh from the ionic documentation?
This is a sample from the doc and I don't understand how could I use it in my project.

```
doRefresh(refresher) {
    console.log('Begin async operation', refresher);

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Async operation has ended');
      refresher.complete();
    }, 2000);
  }
```

Someone can help me?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

add this to ur html

```
<ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
<ion-refresher-content
    pullingIcon="arrow-dropdown"
    pullingText="Pull to refresh"
    refreshingSpinner="circles"
    refreshingText="Refreshing...">
</ion-refresher-content>
```

then in ur do refresh

```
doRefresh(refresher) {
console.log('Begin async operation', refresher);
//ur function e.g getPostWordPress()
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('Async operation has ended');
  refresher.complete();
}, 2000);}
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your answer, it's just the code from the documentation...
The problem is that I'm not able to integrate it with my code to make it works.

Comment: u able to pull to refresh but the list is not refreshing?